# JavaScript promise architecture: Squelch an error

Tags: javascript, dojo, promise

I've been trying to add better promise architecture to our codebase so that there's fewer hardcoded ties between functions, and promises have been useful for that. However, once in a while I have some difficulty figuring out the best way of designing a method.

In this case, here's my stubbed-out functions (sort of pseudocode)

```
/* public function */
function validateUserPreference() {
return askUserPreference().then(saveUserPreference);
}

/* uses several ajax calls and modal dialogs to confirm the user's preference,
  returning true/false in a promise object. */
function askUserPreference() ...

/* Saves the user's preference to the server. Usually, try to call this
  before resolving validateUserPreference, as a convenience to those running it. */
function saveUserPreference() ...
```

Now, here's the tricky bit; error resolution. Often when a series of promises fail, you just want to throw up a dialog to the user telling them something bad happened. But in this situation, I want to try saving the user's preference, BUT it's not a blocker if it doesn't manage to. I don't want to just add `then(saveUserPreference)` and return the original promise, because once `validateUserPreference()` returns, the page is going to submit straight away.

Basically, I'd like to pass along the value from `askUserPreference` in my `then` function, and not resolve it until the other promise finishes, but then somehow ignore any `reject` failures that come up in `saveUserPreference`, and return that same value.

I'm currently using Dojo's promise API, so I can make use of any libraries they have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd imagine you'd have to do something like this:

```
/* public function */
function validateUserPreference() {
  var resolution = askUserPreference();
  return resolution
    .then(saveUserPreference)
    .then(null, function(){
      return resolution;
    });
});
```

Here's a proof of concept to show that `.then()` creates a new promise that can be resolved regardless of the previous promise's rejection:

```
new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
  reject(false);
}).then(null, function(){
  return true;
}).then(function(value){
  console.log('RESOLVED :)', value);
}, function(value){
  console.warn('REJECTED :(', value);
});
```

Running that in your browser's console will result in `RESOLVED :) true` getting output to your console.

Comment: It's possible I'm mis-remembering, but I thought I remembered that if one promise gets rejected, then that rejection gets passed "down the chain"; so the final `.then` in your method would still return as a rejection from saveUserPreference (though instead of an ajax error, it would at least return the result of askUserPreference).

Comment: @Katana314 if you **did** want to continue the rejection down the `then` chain, you would replace the `return` on line 4 of the second code block with `throw`.

Comment: Thanks! I think I had just been thinking of what happens if no errback is specified in `then`; I think then it does chain. But, I hadn't really considered much what would happen with the `return` result of an errback.

Comment: Note that you don’t have to return anything from the errback for it to be converted into a resolved promise, in the same way you do not need to return anything from a catch block in order to prevent an error from throwing in normal javascript.

Comment: @CSnover yes, that is correct. When you don't explicitly return something in a function block, the function will return `undefined`. If you pass a function to the second parameter of `.then()` the only way for it to become rejected is if you `throw` something (probably a `new Error` of some kind) or return another promise that becomes rejected.